# How to impose a limit on the parent items in a query, but if no parent is available, also take the single products in it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The situation we have is:

`product`

A product can have numerous childs, or none. If it **has** childs, it's a `parent` product. If it **has no** childs, it's a `simple` product. But, each child is also a `simple` product.

So:

- 123: `parent`
- - 124: `simple`
- - 125: `simple`
- 140: `simple`
- 141: `parent`
- - 142: `simple`
- 160: `simple`
- 170: `simple`

There's another table named

`product_special`

which has `product_parent_id` and `product_child_id`. If a client has 140 `parent` products, and 870 `simple` products (NOT child products), we want to limit it to 250, and only show those 250, but with the children if applicable. Could be that the first 250 are `simple` products on their own, could be it's 70 `parent`/180 `simple`.

I'm neck deep into this, so I'm not sure if this is clear or not, but any thoughts would be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by UNION:

```
SELECT id FROM product 
     WHERE 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_special WHERE product_parent_id=id)>0
UNION 
SELECT id FROM product 
     WHERE 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_special WHERE product_parent_id=id)=0 
LIMIT 250
```

or by joining subquery and ordering by it:

```
SELECT id, s.cnt AS child_cnt FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT product_parent_id, COUNT(*) cnt 
        FROM product_special 
        GROUP BY product_parent_id
    ) s ON s.product_parent_id=id
ORDER BY child_cnt DESC
LIMIT 250
```